# Default download dialog box not appearing on click of a document link in a document library?

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, feature, download

I am using the code given in [this](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2012/03/stamping-pdf-files-downloaded-from-sharepoint-2010/) link to watermark my documents.

Here the author has used `IHttpHandler` to watermark document whenever a user clicks on a pdf document.

Whenever I click on a document link in the document library the document gets opened inside the browser with the watermark and stuff, instead of showing the default save or cancel dialog box. I don't want the document to get displayed inside the browser and then save it from there. I want to have the default save dialog box that usually appears when you click on document link. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.Name);
```

Comment: Do I have to add this in feature event receiver or in the class where I have implemented IHttpHandler? Sorry for asking such a naive question. I am pretty new to sharepoint

Comment: It should be part of `ProcessRequest` in `PDFWatermarkHttpHandler` when setting `context.Response.ContentType`